# Exclude specific characters from Transliterator conversion

Tags: php, transliteration

I'm trying to make a transliteration using PHP, but what I need is the conversion of all non-latin characters but keep the italian accented characters (àèìòù).

PHP Transliterator lacks of documentation and on-line examples.
I've read the [ICU docs](https://sites.google.com/site/icuprojectuserguide/transforms/general/rules#TOC-Accents) and I know that there is a rule that force Transliterator to convert a char into another specified by us (`à > b`).

The code (using the `create` funciton)

```php
$str = "AŠAàèìòù Chén Hǎi yáo München Faißt Финиш 国内 - 镜像";
$transliterator = Transliterator::create("Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII");
echo $transliterator->transliterate($str);
```

converts all non-latin chars into latin (with all the accented chars) and gives the result

```
ASAaeiou Chen Hai yao Munchen Faisst Finis guo nei - jing xiang
```

and the code (using `createFromRules` function)

```php
$str = "AŠAàèìòù Chén Hǎi yáo München Faißt Финиш 国内 - 镜像";
$transliterator = Transliterator::createFromRules("á>b");
echo $transliterator->transliterate($str);
```

forces correctly the conversion of `à` into `b`, but, obviously, without the conversion `Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII` made by the previous code, giving the result

```
AŠAbèìòù Chén Hǎi ybo München Faißt Финиш 国内 - 镜像
```

So my goal is to merge the `Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII` conversion and the `à > à` rule (and the other italian accented vowels), in order to tell Transliterator to convert all non latin chars to latin, but convert italian accented vowels into themselves, with the following result:

```
ASAàèìòù Chen Hai yao Munchen Faisst Finis guo nei - jing xiang
```

Is there a way to put the `à>à` rule in the `create` function's parameter or add the `Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII` directive in the `createFromRules` function's parameter?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270357/icu-custom-transliteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example with input and output:

```php
$transliterator = Transliterator::create("Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII");
$str = "AŠAàèìòù Chén Hǎi yáo München Faißt Финиш 国内 - 镜像";
echo $transliterator->transliterate($str), "\n";
```

```
ASAaeiou Chen Hai yao Munchen Faisst Finis guo nei - jing xiang
```

when applying the transliteration only on the segments that do not match the range of characters you specified to keep (the italian accented characters [àèìòù]) it should provide the result.

One option is to use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback) for that.

It requires to have a callback to apply the transliteration:

```php
$transliterate = static function (array $match) use ($transliterator) {
    return $transliterator->transliterate($match[0]);
};
```

And it requires to have a pattern to match everything but the characters to keep. It needs to be properly defined and compatible with Unicode:

```
([^\xE0\xE8\xEC\xF2\xF9]+)ui


(...)                : delimiters: the regular expression is inside
u                    : modifier: u - Unicode mode (UTF-8 encoding in
                       PHP, PCRE_UTF8)
i                    : modifier: i - letters in the pattern match
                       both upper and lower case letters
                       (PCRE_CASELESS)

[^...]               : character class: not matching any of the
                       characters (`^`); negated character class
\xE0\xE8\xEC\xF2\xF9 : the italian accented characters àèìòù written
                       in a stable notation (you can easily copy and
                       paste it for example)
```

Last but not least, the subject to operate on must be compatible with the characters to keep. As there can be many ways to write the same character in Unicode, the input is *normalized* to be *compatible* with the PCRE pattern:

```php
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '([^\xE0\xE8\xEC\xF2\xF9]+)ui', 
    $transliterate, 
    Normalizer::normalize($str, Normalizer::NFC)
), "\n";
```

The output:

```
ASAàèìòù Chen Hai yao Munchen Faisst Finis guo nei - jing xiang
```

[Example across PHP versions](https://3v4l.org/8M5PE).

---

Addendum:

- `\xE0\xE1\xE8\xE9\xEC\xED\xF2\xF3\xF9\xFA` lower-case list of italian accented characters (can be used with i-modifier)
- `\xC0\xC1\xC8\xC9\xCC\xCD\xD2\xD3\xD9\xDA\xE0\xE1\xE8\xE9\xEC\xED\xF2\xF3\xF9\xFA` lower- and upper-case list of italian accented characters (can be used without i-modifier)
- PCRE Syntax CHARACTERS (excerpt):

  ```
     \xhh       character with hex code hh
     \x{hhh..}  character with hex code hhh..
  ```
- Link to the full PCRE syntax: https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html

Comment: Thank you really much for your correct and detailed answer, @hakre. You saved my day. The bounty is yours!

Comment: I added all the italian accented chars (also uppercase) and everything works great: `([^\xC0\xC1\xC8\xC9\xCC\xCD\xD2\xD3\xD9\xDA\xE0\xE1\xE8\xE9\xEC\xED\xF2\xF3\xF9\xFA]+)u`

Comment: @Ma3x: Please give the `i` modifier a try. It might be it works with the original regex then already case-insensitive (something I didn't check for the answer but thought about as well today). If the hex-digits grow over 2 places, the notation is a bit different. Missing link to the docs is https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html , specifically with `\xhh       character with hex code hh` and `\x{hhh..}  character with hex code hhh..` (the later shows the requirement to quote with curly braces `{}`. Not necessary in your case, but applies in general.

Comment: @Ma3x And thanks for the bounty and actually a well written question here on SO with a clear and reduced example while looking quite complete also for other languages. We should bring more PHP ICU questions on SO.

Comment: you're right! Using the `i` modifier, I was able to include only lowercase hex codes to keep both lowercase and uppercase italian accented chars. Another good tip. Thank you :) For completion, here is the code: `preg_replace_callback('([^\xE0\xE1\xE8\xE9\xEC\xED\xF2\xF3\xF9\xFA]+)ui', $transliterate, Normalizer::normalize($str, Normalizer::NFC))`

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT] More simple: Use a filter to apply changes only to selected characters:

```
$str = 'AŠAàèìòù Chén Hǎi yáo München Faißt Финиш 国内 - 镜像';

$rules = <<<'RULES'
:: [^ÀàÈèÌìÒòÙù];
:: Any-Latin ;
:: Latin-ASCII ;
RULES;

$tls = Transliterator::createFromRules($rules);

echo $tls->transliterate($str), PHP_EOL;
// ASAàèìòù Chen Hai yao Munchen Faisst Finis guo nei - jing xiang
```

`:: [^ÀàÈèÌìÒòÙù]` is the filter that excludes selected accented letters.

---

[OLD ANSWER] (that works too)
You can play with the normalization to protect accented characters you want to preserve **before** the transliteration from *Any* to *Latin*:

```
$str = 'AŠAàèìòù Chén Hǎi yáo München Faißt Финиш 国内 - 镜像';

$rules = <<<'RULES'
:: NFC ;
à > a ̀  ;
è > e ̀  ;
ì > i ̀  ;
ò > o ̀  ;
ù > u ̀  ;
:: Any-Latin   ;
:: [^ ̀ ]-ASCII ;
:: NFC ;
RULES;

$tls = Transliterator::createFromRules($rules);

echo $tls->transliterate($str), PHP_EOL;
// ASAàèìòù Chen Hai yao Munchen Faisst Finis guo nei - jing xiang
```

This way, accented characters you want to protect with a grave accent are the only in a decomposed form (using a combining character). Those coming from the `Any-Latin` transliteration are in a composed form (they use only one code point).
Then, instead of `Latin` in `Latin-ASCII`, you can use a set that excludes the combining grave accent.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove the `Latin-ASCII` rule.

```php
$str = "AŠAàèìòù Chén Hǎi yáo München Faißt Финиш 国内 - 镜像";
$transliterator = Transliterator::create("Any-Latin; Any-NFC");
echo $transliterator->transliterate($str);
```

Output:

```
AŠAàèìòù Chén Hǎi yáo München Faißt Finiš guó nèi - jìng xiàng
```

You might also want to take the opportunity to apply a normalization rule to the string to compose or decompose the accented characters into a consistent form, depending on what you plan to do with them.

```php
$str = "AŠAàèìòù Chén Hǎi yáo München Faißt Финиш 国内 - 镜像";
$none = Transliterator::create("Any-Latin");
$nfc = Transliterator::create("Any-Latin; Any-NFC");
$nfd = Transliterator::create("Any-Latin; Any-NFD");
var_dump(
    $none->transliterate($str),
    $nfc->transliterate($str),
    $nfd->transliterate($str)
);
```

Output:

```
string(78) "AŠAàèìòù Chén Hǎi yáo München Faißt Finiš guó nèi - jìng xiàng"
string(78) "AŠAàèìòù Chén Hǎi yáo München Faißt Finiš guó nèi - jìng xiàng"
string(93) "AŠAàèìòù Chén Hǎi yáo München Faißt Finiš guó nèi - jìng xiàng"
```

NFC is "composed", as in all accented characters that have a single-codepoint representation are represented as such. NFD is "decomposed" and all accented characters are split into their base codepoint and an accent combining mark. In both cases, multiple combining marks on a single base character will be arranged in a consistent manner.

Some filesystems require a certain form, eg: Mac requires NFD, and some will simply accept anything, eg: ext, creating "duplicate" files with mixed composition that are tricky to deal with.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the output you got from the Any-Latin; Any-NFC rule is not the one I need. I need to convert all non-latin chars, except (àèìòù). So, the output I need is `ASAàèìòù Chén Hai yáo Munchen Faisst Finis guo nei - jing xiang`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` to filter all characters except the italian accented ones and apply transliteration on it.

Answer (score 0):

A method I have used when trying to fend off unwanted transliteration - it's a little ugly, but works with fairly little effort.  Substitute the characters you DON'T want to transliterate with tags, and then replace them after transliteration:

```
<?php

$str = "AŠAàèìòù Chén Hǎi yáo München Faißt Финиш 国内 - 镜像";
$str = str_replace(['à', 'è', 'ì', 'ò', 'ù'], ['@@a@@', '@@e@@', '@@i@@', '@@o@@', '@@u@@'], $str);
$transliterator = Transliterator::create("Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII");
$out = $transliterator->transliterate($str);
$out = str_replace(['@@a@@', '@@e@@', '@@i@@', '@@o@@', '@@u@@'], ['à', 'è', 'ì', 'ò', 'ù'], $out);
echo $out;
```

The result is:

```
ASAàèìòù Chen Hai yao Munchen Faisst Finis guo nei - jing xiang
```